# Got to a particular cell in Excel based on an increase in time

Tags: excel

(Reworded)

I have an excel spreadsheet as per attached. What I would like to know is if I can enter a day, hour, minute value in cells B30, C31, D31 and have it highlight and/or go to the correct cell based on the current time and the time entered in row 30?[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yl1H.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google "Index Match Match".  That should work for you.

Index Match allows you to find a match on one axis.
Index Match Match allows you to find a match on two.